# Is it possible to have multiple authz files for a single subversion repository?

Tags: svn, access-control-list

Is it possible to have multiple authz files for a single subversion repository and to have them interact?

To get a better understanding of what I'm after, let me explain. We're about to roll out centrally hosted subversion repositories for all students at our university. We want to be able to specify groups of users such as teachers and administrators which students can easily give access to. To keep concurrent editing of the ACLs by multiple students simple, we're going to have one authz file for each student. This however makes global group definitions a pain as the group definitions must be updated in at least each authz files that uses it. So my questions basically amounts to, can I have one authz file with group definitions that I then reference from another authz file?

Comment: I dont see any reason why you can't if you are using windows auth via group. You might be better off posting this on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looing at the source to mod_authz_svn (and other parts of the source), I'm not seeing any kind of "include" functionality like you're looking for. Nor am I finding documentation that indicates that such functionaltiy exists.

I'd consider using a scripted solution of some kind to pre-process and build the final authz file from the component files. (You could use m4 for something like this, or your favorite macro processor.)

Comment: Some kind of scripted solution, probably with at database backend and reexporting of dependent files when groups change is our number two option, but multiple authz files would be more elegant (and easy to set).